# Direct Object as Topic

Tags: grammar, particle-は

Can someone please give a simple example of a direct object acting as the topic of a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

本**をば**買いました。
I bought the book.

（＾＾）

（東北で聞いた言い方ですけれども。）

**Additional Detail**

There is an old combination of using は immediately after を, essentially topicalizing the object phrase.  This was more prominent in older times, and it has largely disappeared from modern standard Japanese, persisting mostly in dialect.  When I lived in the Tōhoku region (the northeast of Honshū), I would hear this very occasionally -- mostly used by older folk.

The combination of を{o} + は{wa} causes the は{wa} to change to ば{ba}.  This is a phenomenon called [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku), where certain combinations cause voicing of the initial consonant of the second part.

In terms of meaning, をば is used to emphasize the object of the statement.

Comment: 東北ですか？どの辺？私も東北で住んでいますが、この言い方は聞いた事がないですね。

Comment: @stackreader: しばらく前のことですけれども、盛岡市の周辺にある老人ホームに訪問したときでした。喋られた日本語は老人に限ってさまざまな面でテレビで聞かれる「標準語」と違いました。例として、「らりるれろ」の発音さえ違いまして、まさに英語人が「La, Li, Lu, Le, Lo」をいっていたように聞こえました。

Comment: 東北の老人ですか？それは大変ですね。私なら彼らのしゃべり方がまったくわかりません。

Comment: @stackreader: 自分ならその半分しか理解できませんでした。これはもう日本語じゃない、って感じでした。困っちゃったね!（＾＾）

Answer (score 1):

本は持って来ました。
I brought the book.